# In Perl, how can I disable CGI::Carp that was loaded in a required script?

Tags: perl, cgi

I've got a small Perl program that I want to run on the command line. I need to `require` another Perl script (not a module) that someone else has written. That, in turn, `require`s some other scripts. (I cannot do anything about the way this works).

Now, it is really **annoying** that one of these scripts has `use CGI;` and `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser)` in it. I do not want that. Having 15 lines of `500 Internal Server Error page` on my console every time something breaks is really getting on my nerves. I've tried

```
require 'otherscript.pl';
no CGI;
no CGI::Carp;
```

and

```
no CGI;
no CGI::Carp;
require 'otherscript.pl';
```

to unload it, like the [use doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) describes, but it doesn't work.

Can I somehow manipulate the symbol table or do some other magic to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `unimport` routine in the CGI::Carp package, so `no` has no effect. Undo the relevant part of the `import` routine manually.

Lexical scope (see [caveat](http://p3rl.org/CGI%3a%3aCarp#DOING-MORE-THAN-PRINTING-A-MESSAGE-IN-THE-EVENT-OF-PERL-ERRORS)):

```
local $main::SIG{__DIE__} = \&CGI::Carp::realdie;
```

Global scope:

```
CGI::Carp::set_die_handler(\&CGI::Carp::realdie);
```

Comment: A better way is `CGI::Carp::set_die_handler(\&CGI::Carp::realdie)`. But it is global.

Answer (score 3):

By setting `$CGI::Carp::TO_BROWSER` variable to `0` you can suppress printing the HTML version of die messages.

Comment: I like this answer also, but daxim was faster, so I chose his. Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

Where does the code that uses `fatalsToBrowser` come from? Whilst `fatalsToBrowser` is a really useful development tool, it should only be used in development. In a production environment it can be argued that `fatalsToBrowser` is a security risk as it potentially gives too much information to someone trying to crack your server.

So, by all means use the tricks that other people have mentioned to turn it off. But you should also do whatever you can to ensure that the offending code is changed so that it doesn't use `fatalsToBrowser` in production.

Comment: That is very sound advice. Thank you.